# I need to compile backprots-20131206 into ath10k device driver

Tags: wireless

I need to compile source code backports-20131206 into wireless AP device driver as ath10k
I used 
   `make clean`

```
make defconfig-ath10k
make
```

but I found there are no ath.ko   mac80211.ko   ath9k.ko   ath10k_core.ko   rt2x00lib.ko

rt2x00mmio.ko   rt2x00pci.ko   rt2800lib.ko   rt2800pci.ko

These are device driver for ath10k, how & where can I use the source code to compile

into ath10k for these device driver for wireless AP.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question. What does rt2800 have to do with ath10k_pci?

Answer (score 0):

The compat-20131206 package compiles a driver ath10k_pci, not ath10k. According to its *modinfo*, it depends on ath10k_core, compat and mac80211, all of which are also compiled by the package.

```
filename:       /home/chili/backports-20131206/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/otp.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Atheros QCA988X PCIe devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
version:        backported from Linux (next-20131206-0-gc0a1029) using backports     backports-20131206-0-g0cca7ab
srcversion:     273EBCA0AF429B384C6AD53
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ath10k_core,compat,mac80211
vermagic:       3.12.4-031204-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ath10k_target_ps:Enable ath10k Target (SoC) PS option (uint)
```

Note that firmware is also required by the compiled driver. https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware